# Import images into libreoffice base database without using a form to manually import individual images

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-base

I have a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet that contains the following fields to generate student admit card.

1. Roll number
2. Name
3. Semester
4. Passport sized photograph

and other fields..

The 4th field contains the absolute path of the images. How can I print admit cards of each individual student using Forms in LibreOffice Base?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, first you would need to move your data from Calc into a database, either the Embedded DB in base, HSQLDB 1.8, or some other database you can connect LO to.

Then you need to build a form from that data.

Your question is a good one, but involves many steps, so you have some work ahead to learn how to do these things.  I suggest you start by looking over the documentation for base that I put together [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/80972/to-learn-libreoffice-base-are-there-introductions-or-tutorials/).  Then when you get stuck on smaller questions, search for answers in ask.libreoffice.org or here.

Answer (score 0):

you could try just copy-paste the columns of data from Calc onto a Base Table. This Base Table should have the same columns as the ones you are copying from Calc. It is nicely explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141799/how-can-i-import-calc-data-into-libreoffice-base).